# parse 2-D matrix into link-list

Tags: c++, matrix, linked-list

Here is the matrix I want to represent in the link-list form
[image]

The idea is that it's a 2-D matrix. The font in red is the regular [i][j], and blue is the extra information I want to store in a link-list.

In this matrix, I need to have several informations to be stored.

1. int row
2. int colm
3. int label [as shown in blue]
4. bool value (the value to be displayed on the screen)
5. *** right
6. *** left
7. *** up
8. *** down

the problem is i am going to get 4 link-lists, if I create 4 pointers of array [for 2-D matrix]? how do I even get the directional pointers???

If you are curious, I am working on solving a Karnaugh Map. 
[link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: ... and **why** do you want to store this in a linked list? What should the order of elements be? A structure with 4 pointers (right/left/up/down) in each node isn't a linked list, anyway; it's a graph.)

Comment: I don't get why you can't just work on indices without bothering about linked lists.. then if every element has 4 pointers is not a list anymore. And if they are bidirectional it's a sort of undirected graph.. Just use a bidimensional array of `structs` and live easy!

Comment: Why linked lists? A two-dimensional array would be much simpler for this problem.

Comment: yes you are right. i initially had the undirected graph in mind. i thought of LL because of all the extra information. right. one problem: the adj. matrix of a graph is n*n, meaning i would need 16*16. not big deal for modern pc. and with adj list, i don't know how useful that is over adj. matrix.

Comment: you don't even need an adjacency matrix.. Just a bidimensional array in which you care about the cyclic considerations needed for Karnaugh map (just mod over indices will work)

Comment: thanks guys. hmmm jack, i am not sure how the % works in this case? do you have any idea? when do i use the index mod anyway?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a linked list, use a 2-d array. Quick & dirty (and incomplete):

```
struct Matrix {
    struct Entry {
        int label;
        bool value;
    };

    Entry *array;
    size_t rowlen;

    Matrix(int n) : rowlen(n) { array = new Entry[n*n]; }
    ~Matrix() { delete[] array; }

    Entry &at(int i, int j) { return array[i * rowlen + j]; }

    // etc.
};
```

No need for directional pointers, just use some smart addition and subtraction logic.

Comment: thanks larsmans. i will see what i can learn from your demo code. thanks!